# Azure Logic Apps, SQL Update Row v2

Tags: sql, azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to add an additional task to update a row in SQL Server after sending an email via sendgrid.

The options for updating a row seem to be missing the column name and value. The only additional parameter that can be added is called 'raw inputs' which isn't in the MS documentation.

Completing the available fields and running the process it correctly recognises the rowid that I would expect but I get this error:

> A value must be provided for item.

I can't see where I could provide that value or the column in the row it should be applied to.

Has anyone got this working?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/sql/#update-row-(v2)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will only show the `Row id`, you need to choose `Add new parameter` then it will show `Raw inputs`, it's used to define the value you want to update.

Like the below pic, in my table there are `visit_id` and `test` two property, and then I update the `test` value with `visit_id` equal to 2.

[image]

In the `Raw inputs` I use the json data .

```
{"test":"123"}
```

[image]

Below is my test result, hope this could help you.

[image]