# what do i need to add to make this put request work?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

Thanks for stopping by.

I'm trying to update a SQL row using azure logic apps I'm stuck on this bit, the idea is to get data from a webpage and then update the SQL row. But i dont know what to fill in?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the ID from the http request, you need to change the body of your https trigger [image: Http trigger]. Then you can use the add dynamic content to add the output of first step into 2nd step. [image: Dynamic content]

Comment: thanks alot but i keep getting this error as seen on the question

Comment: Did you check if the row id which you are using actually exists in the table? Your screenshot does not show what the row id is in the raw inputs. Your row id should be a number so the body of your POST request should look like { "ID":5}

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds similar to  this one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092875/azure-logic-apps-sql-update-row-v2). Can you check if the answer helps you?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply it doesnt help me update the rows from the api

Comment: i added rowId set it to 1 and i added a parameter still the database did not update as seen on updated picture

Comment: Did your logic app run successfully? Can you put a snapshot of the inputs and outputs? Your existing snapshot does not show any results. Also, I hope you have done the necessary whitelisting for your logic app to connect to your DB.