# How to insert Http API response into SQL DB using Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, drupal, azure-sql-database, httprequest, azure-logic-apps

I'm developing a graduation project, here data is feed into CMS (build upon Drupal).
The content residing inside Drupal is exposed through [API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api). 
Using Azure Logic App I've to insert the content into SQL database (this part is accomplished) and use that content for a Monitoring System.
Now, I'm facing a **blocker**, when I'm doing Http request and inserting the database.
 But for the second time when job is running I'm not able to check whether content is updated or not. I'm getting duplicate records inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Update row (V2)` instead of Insert row to update the values for specified row based on Row ID or primary key in Logic App.

You can refer [Azure Logic Apps, SQL Update Row v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61092875/azure-logic-apps-sql-update-row-v2).

If you are using Azure SQL DB then you can use query editor to check for changes. Or you can use SSMS in case database is on-premises.